# What does <defunct> mean in the output of ps?

Tags: process, ps, command, process-management

I had issued the `ps -ef|grep java` command and this is one of the entries that  I got :

```
subhrcho   875   803  0 Jan23 pts/5    00:02:27 [java] <defunct>
```

What is `<defunct>` implying here ? What state is that process is that process with PID=875 in ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [ps manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps):

> Processes marked `<defunct>` are dead processes (so-called "zombies")
>   that remain because their parent has not destroyed them properly.
>   These processes will be destroyed by init(8) if the parent process
>   exits.

Comment: what is the contract between a parent process and  child process for destruction of the child process ? I thought it is the duty of the child process to notify the parent that it is being destroyed ?

Comment: @Geek The kernel destroys the child process and notifies the parent. The child only calls `_exit` or dies of a signal. When the kernel destroys a process, all that remains is an entry in the process table, which goes away when the parent (or process 1, for orphans) calls `wait`.

Comment: @Giles  What does it mean when the man page says parent has not destroyed properly the child process ? parent did not call wait ?